# xlCellTypeVisible is not working when creating a range

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to create a range in using VBA in Excel 2010 for only the rows which are visible.  I've already filtered out the values I don't want and I'm using the keyword `xlCelltypeVisible`, and yet, when I test it out the range is still showing the fields in that range which should be hidden.

I've tried several different variations of creating a range, and nothing seems to work.  It simply appears that the `xlCellTypevisible` is not working.

This is not the actual worksheet that I am working with, but for demonstration purposes this sums up exactly what my problem is:

```
Sub create_range()

    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$3:$C$8").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="North"
    Set a = Range("A3", Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

    MsgBox (a(3))



End Sub
```

In this situation I have three columns, A3 = "Opt A", B3 = "Opt B", and C3 = "Opt C".

Under field Opt A I have A, B, C, D, E
Under field Opt B I have 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
Under field Opt C I have North, East, West, South, North

As you can see in my code above I have filtered on the value for "North" in the Field for Opt C.   As a result in column A I see "Opt A", "A", "E".

My expectation is that when i create a range I can select these options, and only these options.  But this is not working.  If is select a(1), I correctly see "Opt A" as A3, which is what I expect.  But when i select the third, and should be final value in the range with a(3), I see "B" instead of "E".

[image: Before filter]

[image: After filter]

Comment: What specific error are you getting?  Why haven't you defined `a` - is it a Range, or an Array?  If you aren't specifying things, then expect "unspecified errors".  However, I suspect the main issue is that Excel is 'filling in' your non-contiguous range to make a contiguous one

Comment: I'm not getting an error.  I'm just getting a different value than the one I expected.  This does not appear to be an issue with me defining my variable. I've tried that as well and it doesn't make a difference.   What i'm looking for is a way to make a range of just the visible cells so that I can access only them for other reasons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue is caused by the way that Excel treats 2 things:  Cells outside of defined Ranges, and Non-Contiguous Ranges

For the first:  if I define `rng = Range("A1:B2")`, and then call `MsgBox rng.Cells(3,3).Address`, it will give me "C3" - even though that is *not* part of the range.  Excel automatically looks outside of the range

For the second:  In your example, `MsgBox a.Address` would give "A3:A4,A8" - a range with 2 [areas](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.areas) (`A3:A4` and `A8`).  When you try to reference it **without** specifying an area, it instead defaults to the *first* area (A3:A4) - and then, as per out first point, extends the range to find a value.

Here is a rough function to return the *n*<sup>th</sup> cell in a non-contiguous column:

```
Function NthCellInColumn(ByRef Target As Range, ByRef Cell As Long) As Range
    Dim DiscardedCells As Long, WhichArea As Long

    DiscardedCells = 0
    For WhichArea = 1 To Target.Areas.Count
        'Is the cell in this area?
        If Cell <= DiscardedCells + Target.Areas(WhichArea).Cells.Count Then
            'Yes, so let's find it
            Set NthCellInColumn = Target.Areas(WhichArea).Cells(Cell - DiscardedCells, 1)
            Exit For 'Stop looping through areas
        Else
            'No, so Discard the Cells
            DiscardedCells = DiscardedCells + Target.Areas(WhichArea).Cells.Count
        End If
    Next WhichArea
End Function
```

Use it like this:  `MsgBox NthCellInColumn(a,3).Value`

Comment: I am confused. How do i tell this function to find the last cell in the range, when I don't know how many rows will be in the range. For example `NthCellInColumn(a,*theLastCell*)`

Comment: @ScottHoltzman `WorksheetFunction.Count(a)`?  It was just a quick / rough function to grab the *nth* item (or return `Nothing` if you go past the end)

Comment: @Chronocidal - gotcha.

Answer (score 2):

Its best practice to always qualify all your objects in VBA. Otherwise, unexpected results can and will happen.

Try this:

```
Option Explicit 'always include this at top of your modules; it forces variable declaration and saves you from massive headaches :)

Sub create_range()

    Dim mySheet as Worksheet
    Set mySheet = Worksheets("Sheet1") 'change as needed

    With mySheet

       .Range("$A$3:$C$8").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="North"

        Dim a as Range 'you need to declare as a range, since you are setting it to a range object
        Set a = .Range("A3", .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

       MsgBox a.Areas.Item(1).Cells(1,1).Value 'first cell

       Dim lastA as Range 'in case the last area is contiguous
       Set lastA = a.Areas.Item(a.Areas.Count)
       Msgbox lastA.Cells(lastA.Rows.Count,1) 'last cell

   End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, Scott.

When I run that code I do see that the values listed in the address are A3, A4, and A8, however, I'm still not able to access them the way I intend.

For example, let's say I want to take the last value in that range, so the letter "E", and move it to the field "E1".   How would I accomplish this through code?   That is what I am really trying to get at.  I need a way to identify the first and last visible values without knowing where they appear on the sheet before the filter is applied.

Comment: Thanks.  I created a new module in my workbook and copy and pasted your code.  For the line "MsgBox a.Areas.Item(1).value" , i got an error: "Run-time error '13': Type mismatch".  in terms of getting the last row for the value of E, that is working perfectly.

Comment: try my new edit, i forgot to put the `.Cells(1,1)` part

Comment: Thanks, but that is returning the "Opt A".  I was hoping to get the first value A.   And just to be clear, I won't always know that it will be the first value below where the filter begins.  it could be row 103 out of 256 rows, and the last value might be 202.  I only did this example for simplicity.

Comment: @Robbie, exclude the header row from `a`

Comment: Thank you for your help.